# INSERT INTO Table from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey so I have a Junction table linking two unrelated tables. Both the tables have `ID`'s. I need to select the `ID` from each table using `WHERE` with different values, for example this is how I see it:

```sql
INSERT INTO c (aID, bID)
VALUES (SELECT a.ID WHERE a.Name="Me", SELECT b.ID WHERE b.Class="Math");
```

All the examples I've seen use a `join` statement but the two tables have a common value, in this case they don't.

Comment: did you try `SELECT ... INTO` ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try this query:

```
     INSERT INTO C (aID, bID) 
     SELECT A.ID, B.ID 
     FROM A, B 
     WHERE A.Name='Me'
     AND B.Class='Math';
```

Comment: cool ill try it, but why "FROM TableA a" why not just "FROM a"

Comment: @Kosmo: I didn't know `A` is your table table, so I used a psuedo table name as TableA and referred TableA using `alias` a. If your tables are `A, B & C` then use as `INSERT INTO C...FROM A, B...`. I updated the answer.

Comment: are you trying to find ID's in one that aren't in the other? if they are not related how can you relate them? Forget about the insert component for now, just get a SELECT statement that returns the data you want. The answer above will give you a cross join of data. i.e. if there are 30 'Me' records in A and 50 'Math' records in B you will get 1,500 records resulting from that. How many records do you expect to get and how should they be correlated between the tables?

Comment: 7 years answer still save my life. Simple as hell, easy to understand. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 9):

Another way can be

```
INSERT INTO c (aID, bID)
SELECT 
   (SELECT A.id FROM TableA A WHERE A.names = 'sometext'), 
   B.id FROM TableB B 
WHERE 
   B.x_name ='othertext';
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming there is only one value in each table for the given `Name` and `Class`, the easiest method is just to enclose your subqueries in `()`:

```
INSERT INTO c VALUES (
(SELECT ID from a where Name='Me'),
(SELECT ID from b where Class ='Math')
)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cd15a651df89af2f9763a15a00e9e88d)

Comment: I don't know is that was possible 7 years ago. But its an cleaner and sometimes faster solution as the accepted one.

Comment: @Lee I'm not sure either. But I was just about to post this answer to a question that got closed as a dupe of this one, so I thought I should post here instead.