# Taking ids from two rows of one MySQL table and entering those values in one row of another MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, named `shows` and `show_connections`. I also ask the user to put in TV show names via POST and those values are `show1connection` and `show2connection`. query is a separately defined function that essentially takes your input and puts it in SQL.

I have the following code:

```
 $show1_name = $_POST["show1connection"];
 $show2_name = $_POST["show2connection"];
 $fail = query ("INSERT INTO show_connections (show1_id) SELECT id FROM shows 
     WHERE name = '$show1name'");
 $fail2 = query ("INSERT INTO show_connections (show2_id) SELECT id FROM shows 
     WHERE name = '$show2name'");
```

My main problem is that I want to set `show1_id` and `show2_id` as the proper ids in one row. Right now, this syntax (which is the closest I've come to solving this problem) does set `show1_id` as id of show 1 and `show2_id` as id of show 2, but they end up on two separate rows. How do I make sure they appear in the same row?

Comment: SQL injection attacks have been a thing for over two decades now. Why have you not learned about parametrized queries yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO Table from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244489/insert-into-table-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: Hi Ignacio, I'm still a beginner at coding, but I will try my best in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try -

```
INSERT INTO show_connections (show1_id, show2_id) 
SELECT s1.id, s2.id 
FROM shows s1, shows s2
WHERE s1.name = '$show1name' 
AND s2.name = '$show2name'"
```

side note - make sure to properly sanitize your user data - `$show1name`/`$show2name`. Even better would be to update your code to `mysqli_` or `PDO` and use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Sean! It worked! I am doing this for a project so this is all going to be hosted on an appliance we have for class. I would assume that's why we haven't been sanitizing user data? Unsure. Thanks again!