# java query select data from two table and insert into another table

Tags: java, mysql

I have two table, one is `traininfo` other is `personalinfo`

- personal info contain PID and train info contain TID (`traininfo`)
- when the user book a train PID and TID  will selected and insert to third table named book info and with the booking ID generate when booked.

So if i want to perform this should i use separate query to add one by one or join the information I want and add it together?

- There is other item within both table and i just want to select this two item

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244489/insert-into-table-from-multiple-tables

Comment: This link will help you checkit out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404682/sql-insert-into-from-multiple-tables

Comment: but both of my table does not share common attribute is it still possible to use join query?