# MySQL, how to insert new data table with join three table

Tags: mysql

I have three data table like this

jan

```
---------------------------------------
id       price        type       
---------------------------------------
1         10          a001       
2         20          a002       
3         30          a003
```

Feb

```
---------------------------------------
id       price        type       
---------------------------------------
1         20          a001       
2         15          a002       
3         18          a003       
4         33          a004
```

Mar

```
---------------------------------------
id       price        type       
---------------------------------------
1         16          a001       
2         40          a002       
3         25          a004       
4         51          a005
```

I need to join three above data to  insert my new table like this

sum

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
id     jan.price   feb.price   mar.price  jan.type   feb.type   mar.type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      10          20          16         a001       a001       a001
2      20          15          40         a002       a002       a002
3      30          18                     a003       a003
4                  33          25                    a004       a004
5                              51                               a005
```

**id** in the new table is auto increment not from the three above.

Please help me to query MySQL syntax.

Comment: update your question with what you have tried code to resolve it

Comment: check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244489/insert-into-table-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following query (the first variant is wrong)

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(jan_price) jan_price,SUM(feb_price) feb_price,SUM(mar_price) mar_price,
  MAX(jan_type) jan_type,MAX(feb_type) feb_type,MAX(mar_type) mar_type
FROM
  (
    SELECT id,price jan_price,NULL feb_price,NULL mar_price,type jan_type,NULL feb_type,NULL mar_type
    FROM Jan

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id,NULL jan_price,price feb_price,NULL mar_price,NULL jan_type,type feb_type,NULL mar_type
    FROM Feb

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id,NULL jan_price,NULL feb_price,price mar_price,NULL jan_type,NULL feb_type,type mar_type
    FROM Mar
  ) q
GROUP BY id
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd9d2a/1

The second variant where data is ordered by type (`id` is generated using `@id` variable)

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  m1.price jan_price,
  m2.price feb_price,
  m3.price mar_price,
  m1.type jan_type,
  m2.type feb_type,
  m3.type mar_type
FROM
  (
    SELECT @id:=@id+1 id,type
    FROM
      (
        SELECT type
        FROM Jan
        UNION
        SELECT type
        FROM Feb
        UNION
        SELECT type
        FROM Mar
      ) t,
      (SELECT @id:=0) n
    ORDER BY type
  ) t
LEFT JOIN Jan m1 ON m1.type=t.type
LEFT JOIN Feb m2 ON m2.type=t.type
LEFT JOIN Mar m3 ON m3.type=t.type
ORDER BY t.id
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd9d2a/23

If you want to put it into a new table with autoincrement field you need the following

```
CREATE TABLE SumTable(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  jan_price int,
  feb_price int,
  mar_price int,
  jan_type varchar(10),
  feb_type varchar(10),
  mar_type varchar(10)
);

INSERT SumTable(jan_price,feb_price,mar_price,jan_type,feb_type,mar_type)
SELECT
  m1.price jan_price,
  m2.price feb_price,
  m3.price mar_price,
  m1.type jan_type,
  m2.type feb_type,
  m3.type mar_type
FROM
  (
    SELECT type
    FROM Jan
    UNION
    SELECT type
    FROM Feb
    UNION
    SELECT type
    FROM Mar
  ) t
LEFT JOIN Jan m1 ON m1.type=t.type
LEFT JOIN Feb m2 ON m2.type=t.type
LEFT JOIN Mar m3 ON m3.type=t.type
ORDER BY t.type;

SELECT *
FROM SumTable
```

---

**The case with `type1 and type2`**

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE Jan(id int,price int,type1 varchar(10),type2 varchar(10));
INSERT Jan(id,price,type1,type2)VALUES
(1,10,'a001','b002'), 
(2,20,'a002','b001'), 
(3,30,'a003','b003');

CREATE TABLE Feb(id int,price int,type1 varchar(10),type2 varchar(10));
INSERT Feb(id,price,type1,type2)VALUES
(1,20,'a001','b001'),   
(2,15,'a002','b001'),   
(3,18,'a003','b003'),   
(4,33,'a004','b003');

CREATE TABLE Mar(id int,price int,type1 varchar(10),type2 varchar(10));
INSERT Mar(id,price,type1,type2)VALUES
(1,16,'a001','b002'),
(2,40,'a002','b002'),
(3,25,'a004','b002'),
(4,51,'a005','b002');
```

Result table

```
CREATE TABLE SumTable(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  jan_price int,
  feb_price int,
  mar_price int,
  jan_type1 varchar(10),
  feb_type1 varchar(10),
  mar_type1 varchar(10),
  jan_type2 varchar(10),
  feb_type2 varchar(10),
  mar_type2 varchar(10)
);
```

Query

```
INSERT SumTable(jan_price,feb_price,mar_price,jan_type1,feb_type1,mar_type1,jan_type2,feb_type2,mar_type2)
SELECT
  m1.price jan_price,
  m2.price feb_price,
  m3.price mar_price,
  m1.type1 jan_type1,
  m2.type1 feb_type1,
  m3.type1 mar_type1,
  m1.type2 jan_type1,
  m2.type2 feb_type1,
  m3.type2 mar_type1
FROM
  (
    SELECT type1,type2
    FROM Jan
    UNION
    SELECT type1,type2
    FROM Feb
    UNION
    SELECT type1,type2
    FROM Mar
  ) t
LEFT JOIN Jan m1 ON m1.type1=t.type1 AND m1.type2=t.type2
LEFT JOIN Feb m2 ON m2.type1=t.type1 AND m2.type2=t.type2
LEFT JOIN Mar m3 ON m3.type1=t.type1 AND m3.type2=t.type2
ORDER BY t.type1,t.type2;
```

Result

```
SELECT *
FROM SumTable
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be68ed/5

Comment: as per asking desired output there should be 5 rows in output with null value that's not matching while in your fiddle its giving only 4 rows

Comment: Check `id` in your `Mar` table as @Laxmi sad - row `(4, 51, a005)`. Maybe, the correct data is `(5, 51, a005)`. I think the query is correct.

Comment: id is auto increment,i think user is expected data on the basis of types column value

Comment: Try the second variant. I've updated my answer. SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd9d2a/23

Comment: @Laxmi - If you mean the fist query it's incorrect because I misunderstood author's expected result at the first time. He wants to order data by `types` and generate new `IDs` for it. It isn't `IDs` from the source tables (Jan, Feb, Mar).

Comment: sorry, but i need' id'
 in the new table is auto increment not from the three above.

Comment: please don't select id from any table. it a primary key and unique.

Comment: I don't do it. I've deleted all the old queries and put only one into my answer.

Comment: @Leran2002 sorry my browser don't refresh i will try your new answer. thank a lot sir.

Comment: OK. I've returned all the variants of queries into my answer.

Comment: @Leran2002 i need some more question sir, if i need to order data by more column like type2, type3 .... how can i do?

Comment: @Leran2002 i mean if table have more column like type2. and i need to left join with type1,type2 sir. now i can order by only type1 with your answer. thank you.

Comment: @Leran2002 can i add more.LEFT JOIN Jan m1 ON m1.type=t.type2
LEFT JOIN Feb m2 ON m2.type=t.type2
LEFT JOIN Mar m3 ON m3.type=t.type2

Comment: @Pubeth Paowijarn - I've added variant with `type1, type2` into my answer. Hope I understood you correctly. SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be68ed/5

Comment: @Leran2002 thank a lot for awesome answer. it can resolve my question.

Comment: @Pubeth Paowijarn - I've just corrected the last query, please check the following `m3.type1=t.type1 AND m3.type2=t.type2`. It was wrong `m3.type1=t.type1 AND m2.type2=t.type2`. I'm glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
id     jan.price   feb.price   mar.price  jan.type   feb.type   mar.type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      10          20          16         a001       a001       a001
2      20          15          40         a002       a002       a002
3      30          18                     a003       a003
4                  33          25                    a004       a004
5                              51                               a005
```

To get the above result you have to modify your third table (Mar table) in which the id is wrong.

please refer:
 SQL Fiddle -http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/680ab2/2

Comment: id is auto increment,i think user is expected data on the basis of types column value

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal May be, even i tried same like your answer. But the output given above is little confusing.

Comment: sorry, but i need 'id' in the new table is auto increment not from the three above.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using joins :

```
select  b.id,a.price as jan_price,b.price as feb_price,
        c.price as march_price,
        a.type as jan_type,
        b.type as feb_type,c.type as march_type
from feb b 
left join jan a on a.type = b.type 
inner join march c on c.id =b.id
```

SQL FIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8898b3/35

Comment: sorry, but i need 'id' in the new table is auto increment not from the three above.