# Use same table in multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get this result but do not know how to achieve it.

```
Client id           Operator Name
---------------------------------
11                     John
12                     Helen
13                     Mark
```

I have 3 tables.

**TableA**

```
clientid             Operatorid
--------------------------------
11                         1
12                        Null
13                        Null
```

**TableB**

```
Operatorid    Operatorname
---------------------------
1             John
2             Helen
3             Mark
```

**TableC**

```
Client id      Operatorid         Description
---------------------------------------------
12              2                   S1
12              2                   S23
13              3                   S1
```

My query is

```
SELECT
    c.ClientID, c.ClientName, b.operatorname
FROM
    Clienttable c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT Clientid, OperatorID 
     FROM tableA) a ON a.ClientId = c.ClientId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tableB ON b.operatorid = a. operatorid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT Clientid, OperatorID 
     FROM tableC 
     WHERE Description LIKE S1) tc ON tc.ClientId = c.ClientId
             tableB b.operatorid = tc. operatorid
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain the logic for combining the tables.

Comment: Hi Gordon, There is one fact table of Clients and then i have  three tables. Table A has client which does not exist in Table B.  for example ClientID 11 does not exist in table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Select client_id and operator_id from tablea and join the tableb to get operator_name (Left Part)

Second, Select client_id and operator_id from table c and join the tableb to get the operator_name (Right Part)

Finally Union both Left and Right for combined Results. (Merge Left & Right)

The below query will do:

```
SELECT 
     a.client_id, 
     a.operator_id, 
     b.operator_name 
FROM tablea a 
JOIN tableb b 
ON a.operator_id = b.operator_id 
UNION 
SELECT 
     c.client_id, 
     c.operator_id, 
     b.operator_name 
FROM tablec c 
JOIN tableb b 
ON c.operator_id = b.operator_id
```

Refer: [INSERT INTO Table from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244489/insert-into-table-from-multiple-tables) for inserting from multiple tables.

Comment: Hi Ashok not working.  because i need one record from table A as well(e.gclientid 11 is missing)

Comment: Hi Salman, Please try the updated query. SELECT a.client_id, c.operator_id, b.operator_name from tablec c inner join tableb b on b.operator_id = c.operator_id inner join tablea a on a.client_id = c.client_id group by a.client_id, b.operator_name, c.operator_id. it is working for me. as the table c does has only two client ids.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your answer by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a series of `join`s like this:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b.Operatorname, b2.Operatorname)
from a left join
     b
     on a.Operatorid = b.Operatorid left join
     c
     on a.clientid = c.clientid and c.description = 'S1' left join
     b b2
     on c.OperatorId = b2.OperatorId
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really feel the filter on `Description` is needed until the `ClientId` and `OperatorId`  pairs are consistent in the `tableC`. `Group By` is used to remove duplicates you can use `distinct` too.

```
WITH CTE_ClientOperatorLink
AS (
    SELECT clientid
        ,Operatorid
        ,Operatorname
    FROM TableB b
    LEFT JOIN TableA a ON b.Operatorid = a.Operatorid
    LEFT JOIN TableC c ON c.Operatorid = b.Operatorid
    GROUP BY clientid
        ,Operatorid
        ,Operatorname
    );

SELECT c.ClientID
    ,c.ClientName
    ,b.Operatorname
FROM Clienttable c
INNER JOIN CTE_ClientOperatorLink b ON c.ClientID = b.Clientid
```

Answer (score -1):

**Hopefully it will work:**

select  a.clientid,b.operationname
from TA a
join
(
select  cliendid,operationid
from TA
union
select  clientid,operationid
from TC
) as q1 on a.clientid=q1.clientid
join TB b on b.operationid=q1.operationid

[image]

thanks